# VB.Net Help with adding data from a text box in a SQL string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to input the data from textbox1 into the section for user= but can't get the syntax right. Please help.

```
Console.WriteLine(sqlQuery("INSERT INTO TESTDATA (User, Status) VALUES ('edavis','Passed')"))
```

Answer (score 1):

See this article.

http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

and/or this one:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml

Be sure you use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.